# How to parametrize these methods?

Tags: android, class, arraylist, parameters

I have the next piece of code:

```
private boolean isResponseHasData(Response<ArrayList<PrefixPhoneModel>> response){
       return (response != null
               && response.body() != null
               && response.body().size() > 0
               && !response.body().isEmpty());
    }

    private boolean isResponseHasErrorBody(Response<ArrayList<PrefixPhoneModel>> response){
        return response != null && response.errorBody() != null;
    }

    private boolean isNoMoreDataToReturn(Response<ArrayList<PrefixPhoneModel>> response){
        return response != null && response.code() != 500;
    }

    private boolean isPreviousCallsWereSuccessful(){
        return getPrefixPhoneModels() != null && !getPrefixPhoneModels().isEmpty();
    }
```

I will need to use these methods with other parameters. Now, I have an ArrayList but I will need to use more types of ArrayLists, ArrayList, ArrayList... etc. The response is the same, but the param changes.

How I can change this methods to accept any ArrayList.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the generic wildcard `?`:

```
private boolean isResponseHasErrorBody(Response<ArrayList<?>> response){
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, use `? extends [Some type here without brackets]` if you want a specific class inheritance.

And if you wanted any child of the List class, just replace `Response<ArrayList<?>>` with `Response<List<?>>`, or alternatively use `Response<Collection<?>>`.

---

Or, since the type of the nested list doesn't matter, you can use `Response<List>` or `Response<Collection>`. Using the generic wildcard in a nested List doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes, but If I use "isResponseHasErrorBody(response)" and "response is type of ArrayList<PrefixPhoneModel>" the IDE marks this as an error.

Comment: Using this "Response<? extends Collection<?>> response" the error dissappear

Comment: The error said that Response<ArrayList<?>> is not the same than ArrayList<PrefixPhoneModel>. And It instance me to change the types.

Comment: It still has to be wrapped in a response, so if you passed an ArrayList with PrefixPhoneModel with a Response<List<?>> input type, it ends up being wrong

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
public <E, L extends Collection<E>>  boolean isResponseHasData(Response<L> response);
```

or

```
public <L extends Collection<?>>  boolean isResponseHasData(Response<L> response);
```

or just

```
public boolean isResponseHasData(Response<? extends Collection<?>> response);
```

---

The first is cool if you need to set boundaries on the type:  `<E extends MyObject, ... >`

Comment: alright maybe I didn't get the part `more types of ArrayLists, ArrayList, ArrayList... etc`. I guess you needed different `Collection` types

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need move these methods to another class

```
class ResponseValidator<T> {
    private boolean isResponseHasData(Response<ArrayList<T>> response){
       return (response != null
               && response.body() != null
               && response.body().size() > 0
               && !response.body().isEmpty());
    }

    private boolean isResponseHasErrorBody(Response<ArrayList<T>> response){
        return response != null && response.errorBody() != null;
    }

    private boolean isNoMoreDataToReturn(Response<ArrayList<T>> response){
        return response != null && response.code() != 500;
    }

    private boolean isPreviousCallsWereSuccessful(){
        return getPrefixPhoneModels() != null && !getPrefixPhoneModels().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ResponseValidator<PrefixPhoneModel> responseValidator = new ResponseValidator<>();

responseValidator.isResponseHasErrorBody(response);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply omit type parameters and use methods like

```
private boolean isResponseHasErrorBody(Response response){
    return response != null && response.errorBody() != null;
}
```

You may lint warnings like unchecked cast. You may disable them with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation

or you can parametrize method like

```
private <T extends ArrayList> boolean isResponseHasErrorBody(Response<T> response){
    return response != null && response.errorBody() != null;
}
```

Comment: This would allow any type of response, while OP wants any type of ArrayList response: `How I can change this methods to accept any ArrayList.`

Comment: Can you move these methods to another class or is it impossible ?